# How do you get values inside of array that is in another array

Tags: node.js, arrays, google-sheets, discord.js

So i tried to get rows from my google sheet using spreadsheets.values.get and the output of values look something like this.

```
[
   'Name',
   'Date',
   'Rate',
   'Description',
   'Seasons'
],
[
   '2Name',
   '2Date',
   '2Rate',
   '2Description',
   '2Seasons'
],
```

Its array in array i think, im not that good in coding, and i wanted to get Name, date, rate ,desc and seasons into vars, post it as embed through discord.js and repeat until array end

Here's the entire code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis')
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: 'keys.json',
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
        });

        GetValues();

        async function GetValues() {
          const googleClient = await auth.getClient();
          const googleSheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: googleClient});
          const spreadsheetId = 'IDHere';

          try {
            const response = (await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
              auth,
              spreadsheetId,
              range: 'A2:E',
              valueRenderOption: 'FORMATTED_VALUE',
              dateTimeRenderOption: 'SERIAL_NUMBER'
            })).data;
            console.log(response.values);
            //return(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        };
```

If you need more info ask in the comments pls, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, generally you can access an array inside an array like you normally would.

That means `data[0]` would be the first entry inside the outer array. You can either save that in a value or just loop over each element of the outer array, thats up to you. Once you have the inside you can do pretty much the same.

What you can also do is `data[0][0]` which would be the first value of the first element in the outer array.

So using your example data:

```
const data = [
[
   'Name',
   'Date',
   'Rate',
   'Description',
   'Seasons'
],
[
   '2Name',
   '2Date',
   '2Rate',
   '2Description',
   '2Seasons'
]
];
```

`const firstElement = data[0];` will return

```
[
   'Name',
   'Date',
   'Rate',
   'Description',
   'Seasons'
]
```

which you can then split up again using the same method.

On the other hand `data[0][0]` will return `'Name'`.